# Idiomatic ruby code - simple for each casuing confusing for me

Tags: ruby

Im very new to ruby and cant determin if i am using the ruby language correctly.  I want find out if any one of an array of numbers is divisible by another number.  If so return that number otherwise, return 0.

```
  def is_divisible(nums, n)
    nums.each do |m|
      if n % m == 0
        return n
      end
    end
    0
  end
```

The function works correctly but there are a few aspects to it which i think are not idiomatic of ruby:

1. Should i check if `nums` is of a type that can be looped first or catch an exception (coming from php and python I know these think differently but cant tell with ruby yet)
2. Is there a more concise way to structure the loop and the 2 separate return values
3. Anything else that isnt correct with this code?

Comment: Your method confuses me, too :-) Could you provide some examples of desired input and output?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review, which would be better suited to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Here are my thoughts:

**Naming**: Predicate methods in Ruby are named `predicate?` and not `is_predicate`, so the name of your method should be `divisible?` … except that it *isn't* actually a predicate. It doesn't test whether a number is divisible by another number, rather it finds the first number in an `Enumerable` which is divisible by another number. That sentence almost sounds like a descriptive method name, doesn't it?

```
def find_first_divisible(nums, n)
  nums.each do |m|
    if n % m == 0
      return n
    end
  end
  0
end
```

**Naming cont'd**: We don't charge you for your characters. You can use more of them if you want ;-) `nums` is probably okay, `n` is on the fence, but what the heck is `m`? In fact, you have a bug there, which is caused precisely by you confusing `n` and `m`.

```
def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.each do |n|
    if n % divisor == 0
      return n
    end
  end
  0
end
```

**Guard clauses**: For cases like this, where you want to use `return` (or `next`) to break out early, I prefer to use a guard clause style of the form "do this if that":

```
def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.each do |n|
    return n if n % divisor == 0
  end
  0
end
```

**One line blocks**: In this case, the contents of the block are short enough to fit on one line, so I would do that. Note that there are two competing styles for block formatting: one says to always use `do`/`end` for multiline blocks and always use `{`/`}` for single line blocks. The other says to always use `do`/`end` for blocks which are used primarily for their side-effects ("imperative blocks") and `{`/`}` for blocks which are used primarily for their return value ("functional blocks"). I prefer the latter style.

```
def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.each do |n| return n if n % divisor == 0 end
  0
end
```

**Descriptive methods**:

```
def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.each do |n| return n if (n % divisor).zero? end
  0
end
```

**Know the core and standard libraries**: This is very important, you don't want to reinvent the wheel!

```
def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.find {|n| (n % divisor).zero? } || 0
end
```

Note how I changed the block style: now we are interested in the return value, there are no side-effects.

**Extract methods with meaningful names**:

```
class Integer
  def divisible_by?(n) (self % n).zero? end
end

def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.find {|n| n.divisible_by?(divisor) } || 0
end
```

Now, the method reads *exactly* like your description in the question: "within `numbers`, find the first `n` which is `divisible_by` the `divisor`, and if there is none, the result is `0`".

**Respect conventions**: Last but not least, you should respect the conventions of the community. Methods that search for something should return `nil` to indicate the absence of a result:

```
def find_first_divisible(numbers, divisor)
  numbers.find {|n| n.divisible_by?(divisor) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should post questions like that to CodeReview SE page. Now to your questions:

1. It is typical for ruby not to do this to allow duck typing. Rubbyist assumes that programmers are intelligent enough not to call `is_divisible` method on strings.
2. Ruby comes with extended Enumerable module which I strongly reccommend to get familiar with: ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html. There is for example method `find` which will do exactly what you need:

   ```
   def is_divisible(num, n)
     num.find{|number| number % n == 0} || 0
   end
   ```
3. Your code seems all right, however I would reconsider its name - i would expect it to return true or false rather than first divisible number. Also when you use simple conditionals to execute just one line use it like:

   ```
   return n if n % m == 0
   ```

   You can use similar rules to `do end` and `{}` blocks:

   ```
   nums.each {|m| return n if n % m == 0 }
   0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby core `Array` class contains many useful features, that query and/or re-structure arrays in generic ways when given a block that defines what you are interested in.

Taking your written description:

> I want find out if any one of an array of numbers is divisible by another number. 
>   If so return that number otherwise, return 0.

You could do this:

```
def is_divisible( nums, n )
  nums.find { |x| x % n == 0 } || 0
end
```

using the built-in `Array#find` method.

However, it would not usually be idiomatic Ruby to return a `0` when you don't have a match.  How would you differentiate between a list which contains `0` and the default? So usually I would structure the code like this:

```
def find_first_divisible( nums, n )
  nums.find { |x| x % n == 0 }
end

# If you really need default 0 for no match:

result = find_first_divisible( my_nums, divisor ) || 0
```

Also the method has become so trivial, and understanding `.find` statements is easy (compared to looking up definition of a custom method), that I probably would not create a method here unless it was being called in multiple places. That's a personal choice.

For checking types, I tend to do that defensively in factory methods and/or `initialize`, and not so much elsewhere. That's a more complex discussion though - whole books could be written on typing systems, approaches to validation and testing, and how different languages lend themselves to different approaches.